# using post ID inside reverse ACF relationship querie

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I’m using relationship field on one of my custom post type (releases).

all my realease have a relationship field with “artists” post, so all my releases are associated with one artist.

now i’m trying to perform a reverse query to display all the “releases” associated with the artist selected in my relationship field.

here is my code so far :

```
<?php 
$releases = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'releases',
'numberposts'=> -1,
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key' => 'artist',
'value' => 191,
'compare' => 'LIKE'
)
)
));?>
<?php if( $releases ): ?>
<?php foreach( $releases as $release ): ?>

<div class="col-xs-2 text-center">

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $release->ID ); ?>" class="related_releases" title="<?php echo get_the_title($release->ID); ?>">

<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($release->ID, 'full'); ?>">

</a>

</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

with this code, all the releases from artist ID “191” are displayed on y custom post type.

the problem is that I’m trying to display the releases from the artist associated with the “release” post.

what I’m trying to do is to get the ID of the artist inside my querie, like this (width “get_the_ID()” instead of “191”)

```
<?php 
$releases = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'releases',
'numberposts'=> -1,
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key' => 'artist',
'value' => get_the_ID(),
'compare' => 'LIKE'
)
)
));?>
```

but I get the ID of the “release” post, not the ID of the artist.

can anyboby help me with this ?

hope you understand my issue, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Will this work instead in your array

```
'value' => get_the_author_meta( $user_id ),
```

Comment: thanks, but mu querry has nothing to do with the autor or user

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. i think this will work.

```
   <?php 
$artist       =  get_post_meta (get_the_ID(),'artist');
$releases = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'releases',
'numberposts'=> -1,
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key' => 'artist',
'value' => $artist[0],
'compare' => 'LIKE'
)
)
));?>
<?php if( $releases ): ?>
<?php foreach( $releases as $release ): ?>

<div class="col-xs-2 text-center">

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $release->ID ); ?>" class="related_releases" title="<?php echo get_the_title($release->ID); ?>">

<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($release->ID, 'full'); ?>">

</a>

</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks @sheraz, I tried to add you code but it doesn't work. Can you please tell me where to add your code ? I have a doubt

Comment: thanks but it's not working, I've found the solution, please read below

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution :

```
<?php

$posts = get_field('artist'); if( $posts ): 
foreach(array_slice($posts, 0, 1) as $post):
setup_postdata($post);
$post_ID =  get_the_ID();
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;

$releases = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'releases',
'numberposts'=> -1,
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key' => 'artist',
'value' => $post_ID,
'compare' => 'LIKE'
)
)
));?>
<?php if( $releases ): ?>
<?php foreach( $releases as $release ): ?>

<div class="col-xs-2 text-center">

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $release->ID ); ?>" class="related_releases" title="<?php echo get_the_title($release->ID); ?>">

<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($release->ID, 'full'); ?>">

</a>

</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```